# Mean value theorem when derivative might be infinite

Tags: calculus

Wikipedia's entry for the Mean Value Theorem states that it is valid in a more general context. Explicitly, if $f : [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ and for every $x \in (a, b)$ the derivative $f'(x)$ exists as an extended real number (that is, $f'(x)$ might be $\infty$ or $-\infty$), then there is $c \in (a, b)$ such that

$$f'(c) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}$$

What is the proof of that? Is the result valid if, say, for one $x \in (a, b)$ we have $f'(x^+) = \infty$ and $f'(x^-) = -\infty$?

**Edit:** Wikipedia's entry says exactly the following:

"The mean value theorem is still valid in a slightly more general setting. One only needs to assume that $f : [ a , b ] → \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $[ a , b ]$, and that for every $x \in ( a , b )$ the limit

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$$

exists as a finite number or equals $\infty$ or $-\infty$."

Comment: To your second question, consider the function $f$ on $[0,1]$ whose graph is a triangle of height $1$ and base $1$. Then $f(b) - f(a) = 0$ but $f$ is always either strictly increasing or decreasing.

Comment: $c\in]a,b[$ and the $f'$ must to exist and it must be continuous. IMHO not exists the mean value theorem in these conditions.

Comment: What does your notation $f’(x^+)$ and minus mean? If I’m taking it to mean the right handed/left handed derivatives, I.e, limit as h goes to zero from the right/left of the difference quotient, if those two don’t match then $f’(x)$ would not exist for that x, but you’re assuming it does for all $x \in (a,b)$?

Comment: Yes, $f'(x^+)$ is the right handed derivative and $f'(x^-)$ is the left handed derivative. For the second question I am not assuming that $f'(x)$ exists for this particular $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Pick your favorite constant $M>0$. $f'(x+0)=+\infty$ would imply that $f'>M$ on $(x, x_1)$ for some $x_1>x$ and $f'(x-0)=-\infty$ would imply that  $f'<-M$ on $(x_2, x)$ for some $x_2<x$. But this would mean that $f'$ is not Darboux, which is absurd.

Comment: Why would this be absurd?