# Proof for mean value theorem with relaxed condition

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

On the Wikipedia page for mean value theorem, the following mean value theorem with relaxed condition is shown

> The mean value theorem is still valid in a slightly more general setting. One only needs to assume that $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, and that for every $x$ in $(a,b)$ the limit $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
> exists as a finite number or equals $\infty$ or $-\infty$.

I would like a proof (or a reference that contains it). [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3789964/mean-value-theorem-when-derivative-might-be-infinite) asked the same question but no actual answer was given.

Comment: A generalized version of Rolle's theorem is stated (with proof!) in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem, and that implies the generalized mean value theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By subtracting an affine function from $f$, we may without loss of generality suppose that $f(a)=f(b)=0$ (this is the usual reduction to Rolle’s theorem that takes place even in the usual proof of the MVT), and we only need to prove the existence of a point $\xi\in (a,b)$ such that $f’(\xi)=0$. If $f$ is constant, this is obvious, so suppose $f$ is not constant.

By the extreme-value theorem, $f$ has a global minimum value $m$ and global maximum value $M$ on $[a,b]$. We have $m<M$ and $m\leq 0\leq M$. So, atleast one of these quantities is not equal to $0$. By replacing $f$ with $-f$, we may suppose that $M>0$. Let $\xi\in [a,b]$ be a point such that $f(\xi)=M$; now note that since $M>0$ we definitely have that $\xi\in (a,b)$. All that is left to be shown is that $f’(\xi)$ exists in the proper sense and equals $0$. This is easy:

- If $x\in (a,b)$ is a point such that $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\infty$, then for sufficiently small $h>0$, we have $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}>1$, and hence $f(x+h)>h+f(x)>f(x)$, so the point $x$ cannot be a local maximum point. Hence, our global maximum point $\xi$ from above cannot satisfy $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(\xi+h)-f(\xi)}{h}=\infty$.
- Similarly, $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(\xi+h)-f(\xi)}{h}=-\infty$ is not possible.

Therefore, $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(\xi+h)-f(\xi)}{h}$ exists in $\Bbb{R}$, i.e $f’(\xi)$ exists in the proper sense. Now, apply the basic theorem that if a function has a (global, hence) local maximum at an interior point $\xi\in (a,b)$ and $f$ is differentiable at $\xi$, then $f’(\xi)=0$ (you look at the left and right limits and argue they must have opposite signs and hence must both vanish). This completes the proof.

Intuitively, at a point with $+\infty$ as derivative, the function attains larger values to the right of that point (and smaller values to the left), so that point cannot be a local maximum (draw a picture). The opposite happens at points with $-\infty$ as derivative. So, we can safely ignore such points, and thus we’re back to the good old situation, and our familiar argument there works. All these other reductions are merely there to ‘streamline’ the argument as much as possible. If you really wanted, you could consider all the various cases.

Comment: Great answer and also thanks for the intuitive explanation.

Comment: The argument can be simplified a bit (IMO): From considering the left and right limit of the differential quotient at $\xi$ you can conclude that both $f'(\xi) \ge 0$ and $f'(\xi) \le 0$ must hold, that excludes the cases $f'(\xi) = \pm \infty$.

Comment: @MartinR oh perfect, this is even more direct. (but I’ll leave things as is, because I’m getting tired of editing :)